# my question is not updating even after changing the index to that question

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-state, flutter-functional-widget

what i want in this code is that the questions to change to the next one in the map whenever the user presses any of the true of false buttons, but the question is not updating even after changing the index and using setstate. I don't know what is wrong here. Please go through the code and check if there are any other issue. Thank You!
My code is as:

```
class _QuestionQuizState extends State<QuestionQuiz> {
  late Map<String, bool> _ques;
  List marks = [];
  double index = 0;
  String t = 'true';
  String f = 'false';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ques = widget.questions;
  }

  String display() {
    final questionNo = _ques.keys.elementAt(index.toInt()).toString();
    return questionNo;
  }

  void chooseAnswer(index, text) {
    final answer =
        _ques.values.elementAt(index.toInt()).toString().toLowerCase();
    setState(() {
      if (answer == text) {
        marks.add('1');
      } else {
        marks.add('0');
      }
      index += 1;
      display();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('hello'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Colors.black,
                  Colors.brown,
                ],
              ),
              // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                display(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.black,
                      Colors.brown,
                    ],
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    chooseAnswer(index, t);
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'True',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 20),
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.black,
                      Colors.brown,
                    ],
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    chooseAnswer(index, f);
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'False',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          DisplayResult(
            marks: marks,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried changing the index and took inside the build so that whenever the setstate rebuilds it would change the my question, but alas it did now work aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion is using same variable name `index`

```dart
void chooseAnswer(index, text) {
```

You already have state `index` variable. while you are incrementing the `index` it is updating.

```dart
void chooseAnswer(index, text) { //this index being function scope
```

Not the state `index`. You can remove it or use different name.

I am ignoring the parameter like

```dart
 void chooseAnswer(_, text) {
```

Comment: thanks a lot once again! 
Your solutions always solve my queries :)

Comment: Glad to help, you an check more about [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting variable ex:

```
var questionText = display();
```

use this variable in your Text field and recall in setState.
btw why don't you declare index as int?

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you. About not using int, I tried using it but idk i was getting a weird "not of type double" error